# Closing thread pool down after all work items are complete

Tags: c, windows, multithreading

I am using the Windows Thread Pool API [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/thread-pool-api).

Right now I pass a path to my thread pool from my main thread. Then my main thread waits using `WaitForThreadpoolWorkCallbacks` on the work item. Then the pool does work on each individual file in that directory. This is bad because it is basically using one thread to handle the entire directory.

What needs to happen is my main thread loops through the directory and places each file onto the thread pool queue using `CreateThreadpoolWork` and `SubmitThreadpoolWork`.

The Issue:

If I am having my main thread place items (file paths) into a queue, I will need to create another queue that keeps track of all the `PTP_WORK` structs so that I can check them and wait for them.

Other than creating a linked list, is it possible to just wait on the thread pool and it report to me somehow that none of the threads are working? Then I would know it is time to close out.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for CloseThreadPool?

Comment: I thought that was what I needed but doesn't work like I thought. I basically need something that blocks my main program from ending until all work items are completed. If I call this function it doesn't block and my program just ends and all the work isn't completed.

Comment: for what you need wait for callbacks ? and i sure that CreateThreadpoolWork and SubmitThreadpoolWork wrong solution when you enum folder. you need instead use CreateThreadpoolIo + ZwQueryDirectoryFile